# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Configuration in Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can the configurations in appsettings.json be accessed from a non-static class that is not a controller and can't receive IOptions in the constructor?

Comment: Why can't it receive IOptions?  Can it receive a POCO instead?

Comment: Not as far as I know, for example in a class that extends System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext with some built-in settings.

Comment: I've fixed it in a different manner which is not ideal, so the question still stands though

Comment: Does this question still stand? Hasn't my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use property or method injection? And are you allowed to change the default container? If so:

First change your default container to for instance Autofac (reference Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection version 4.0.0-rc1-177 in your project.json). Change your ConfigureServices as follows:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddMvc();

 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.Populate(services);
 var container = builder.Build();
 return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

Use Autofac to wire up your class via property or method injection. You can read here how to: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html